# Hessenberg power of ordinals (redux)

Tags: set-theory, exponentiation, order-theory, ordinals, well-orders

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3447931/hessenberg-power-of-ordinals), in which the given definition failed.

Let $f : \varepsilon_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ recursively defined by
\begin{align}
    f\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \omega^{\beta_i} c_i\right)
    &= \sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{id}_\mathbb{N}^{f(\beta_i)} c_i
\end{align}
where the argument to $f$ is in [Cantor normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Cantor_normal_form) and all arithmetic operations between functions are defined pointwise. Notice that

\begin{align}
\alpha +_H \beta &= f^{-1}(f(\alpha) + f(\beta)) \\
\alpha \cdot_H \beta &= f^{-1}(f(\alpha) \cdot f(\beta))
\end{align}
where $+_H$ and $\cdot_H$ are the [Hessenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Natural_operations) sum and product of ordinals. Let
\begin{align}
\alpha \uparrow_H \beta = f^{-1}(f(\alpha)^{f(\beta)})
\end{align}
This seems to be the natural candidate for "Hessenberg exponentiation" (at least for ordinals below $\varepsilon_0$), satisfying properties one would expect, such as

\begin{align}
    \alpha \uparrow_H (\beta +_H \gamma)
    &= f^{-1}(f(\alpha)^{f(\beta +_H \gamma)}) \\
    &= f^{-1}(f(\alpha)^{f(\beta) + f(\gamma)}) \\
    &= f^{-1}(f(\alpha)^{f(\beta)} \cdot f(\alpha)^{f(\gamma)}) \\
    &= f^{-1}(f(\alpha \uparrow_H \beta) \cdot f(\alpha \uparrow_H \gamma)) \\
    &= (\alpha \uparrow_H \beta) \cdot_H (\alpha \uparrow_H \gamma) \\
\end{align}

Does it have a purely order-theoretic definition, like the Hessenberg sum and product? Can it be extended to all ordinals?

Comment: I don't understand your definition of $f$. Specifically, what do you mean by $g^h$ for functions $g,h$? (I'm trying to parse the "$id_\mathbb{N}^{f(\beta)}$" bit.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Pointwise power.

Comment: You mean $(g^h)(x)=g(x)^{h(x)}$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber That's right.

Comment: And presumably "$hc$" is pointwise multiplication by $c$ and "$\sum$" is pointwise addition?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Exactly.

Comment: You should maybe state that this is an inductive definition because readers might not understand why $f$ appears in the exponent of $id_{\mathbb{N}}$. Otherwise I think this is an interesting question. Have you tried comparing this to your former "order-theoretic" exponentiation on simple examples? Have you computed $\omega \uparrow 2$ with your former definition?

Comment: @nombre: For any natural $n$, this definition gives $\omega\uparrow_H n = \omega^n$.

Comment: @celtschk: I was thinking of the definition given [here][1]. To me it seems that this one coincides with the regular ordinal exponentiation.


  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3711862/hessenberg-power-of-ordinals-redux

Comment: @nombre: You seem to link back to the very post you are commenting on; I guess you meant to link to another one.

Comment: @celtschk Indeed. It is rather in the beginning of this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3704714/cauchy-completion-of-transfinite-rationals.

Comment: @user76284 Note that you should first justify that $f(\alpha)^{f(\beta)}$ always lies in the range of $f$, so that you can consider its preimage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this exponentiation formula is not defined for all ordinals.

For example, assume
$$\alpha=2\uparrow_H\omega$$
According to the formula, this would imply that
$$f(\alpha)(n) = 2^n$$
Now since ordinals are totally ordered, either $\alpha<\omega^\omega$ or $\alpha\ge\omega^\omega$.

If $\alpha<\omega^\omega$, it is a polynomial in $\omega$, therefore $f(\omega)(n)$ is a polynomial in $n$. Clearly $2^n$ is not a polynomial in $n$.

On the other hand, if $\alpha\ge\omega^\omega$, then for sufficiently large $n$, $f(\alpha)(n)\ge n^n$. However $2^n<n^n$ for $n>2$.

Thus $\alpha$ can neither be less than $\omega^\omega$ nor greater or equal, which is a contradiction.

Comment: What if we restrict the base of the exponent to $\omega$, as in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371535/every-non-increasing-sequence-of-polynomial-towers-stabilizes-finitary-proof)? The polynomial towers are isomorphic to the ordinals below $\varepsilon_0$, much like the polynomials are isomorphic to the ordinals below $\omega^\omega$.

Comment: If the base is restricted to $\omega$, then you indeed get a well-defined operation. I think it will agree with the conventional ordinal power in that case.